# Should i store Arraylist or extend it?

Tags: java, arraylist

i am making a game and it uses a gird
i can implement it by extending arraylist
for example:

```
public class Grid extends ArrayList<ArrayList<obj>> 
{
     public void addObj(Obj obj ,int x, int y)
     {
           get(x).set(y,obj);
     }
}
```

or should i do it by storing it

```
public class Grid
{
      private ArrayList<ArrayList<obj>> objs = new ArrayList<...>();

       public void addObj( Obj obj, int x, int y)
       {
          objs.get(x).set(y,obj);
       }
}
```

help plz

Comment: @Kayaman I don't think it's a duplicate question. That question is a generic approach about how to solve those problems, but you may use that Q/A to support your answer.

Comment: There's no right answer. Technically, a grid "**is a[n]**" ArrayList, but I'd go for composition anyway.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Not a duplicate no, but the message is still pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it is better to use composition over inheritance. You should only make your class to extend from `ArrayList` (or any other class in the Java Collection Framework) in case you need to alter specific behavior of that class like `add` method.

By the way, you should declare the variable as `List` instead of `ArrayList`. Always code oriented to interfaces rather than specific implementation classes.

The code should look like this:

```
public class Grid {
    private List<List<obj>> objs = new ArrayList<List<obj>>();
    public void addObj( Obj obj, int x, int y) {
        objs.get(x).set(y,obj);
    }
}
```

More info:

- [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49002/1065197)
- [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197)

Answer (score 3):

The latter, compositional approach. ArrayList is how you choose to implement Grid now, but you might want to used Map or a different List type in the future.

Plus, some of ArrayList's methods are likely meaningless in the context of a Grid, e.g. subList.

Answer (score 1):

Does `Grid` satisfy the following : **Grid-is-a-ArrayList** ? I would say not.

I would much rather use composition in this case. Your grid will provide a completely different (richer?) interface to a list.

Note that if you really need `List` semantics, you can implement the interface `java.util.List` on your `Grid` without actually inheriting the implementation. That will give you your desired contract but leaving the implementation up to you (whether you choose to delegate to a real list or not...)